# Definition of the trace of a stationary set

Tags: set-theory

Definition 8.17 of Jech's, *Set Theory*, Third Millennium Edition, states that the trace of a stationary subset $S$ of a cardinal $\kappa$ is $Tr(S)$ = {$\alpha<\kappa: cf(\alpha)>\omega$ and $S\cap\alpha$ is stationary}. I question the requirement $cf(\alpha)>\omega$, because this would imply $Tr(S)=\emptyset$ for any stationary subset $S\subset\aleph_{1}$. Any thoughts?

Comment: The requirement cf$(\alpha)>\omega$ is intentional, and, as you notice, all subsets of $\omega_1$ have empty rrace. Note that, for ordinals $\alpha$ of cofinality $\omega$, the notion of "$X$ is a stationary subset of $\alpha$" is either undefined or (my preference) false for all $X$.

Comment: Thanks. Just thought I should double check. But doesn't this mean that Theorem 8.20 is only good for $\kappa>\aleph_1$? Otherwise, there is no set $C_n$ because $Tr(A_{n+1})$ is empty.

Comment: Jech's proof of Theorem 8.20 seems designed for $\kappa>\aleph_1$, but the theorem is true also for $\kappa=\aleph_1$, for a very simple reason. When $\kappa=\aleph_1$, no stationary sets have $S<T$; see the definition 8.18 of $<$ and the parenthetical statement immediately after it.

Comment: Aha! I missed that. Thanks.